# Unlocking iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios

My sister had locked her phone by downloading the IOS 8 and in the process she had turned off her phone. Her whole phone had then locked out and started over. Logically, we would take  the phone and put in the iCloud account with the iCloud email and password but the problem is she does not know her password so we went to recover it but she keeps getting the security questions wrong and she forgot what email she used to recover the iCloud account. I´d really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Locked is locked, that's the whole idea.

If https://iforgot.apple.com doesn't help, then next would be to phone Apple & see if they can help. [Apple Support phone number list, by country](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE57?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)